# The way to use double redis-cluster

Tags: redis

I want to use the list which redis support. My plan is that use the one redis cluster to save data in memory,and use the other to save data persistence.

If the plan is vaild?

Comment: You could do both with the same cluster, could you provide more information about why you'd like to do it with two?

Comment: I consider to use one redis  as memory db, the web get data through it first. The other one redis as persistence db, just like mysql . The reason is I want to use the struct "list" and it only suppurted by redis.

Comment: Redis is always in-memory, but supports persisting to file, so you could do the same thing with just one instance of redis

Comment: I see, but I consider when redis supports persisting it's performance will be low.

Comment: If performance becomes an issue, you can disable persistence on the master and have it on the slave only, no need for multiple clusters.

Comment: Thanks,It provides a new idea for me.